# How to pass data in JSON format in angular-file-upload directive

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-file-upload

I am using **`angular-file-upload`** directive for uploading a file in my application. And also I want to send some form data in JSON format along with the file. Using this configuration for uploading.

```
Upload.upload({
    url: "https://angular-file-upload-cors-srv.appspot.com/upload",
    fields: $scope.conf,
    sendObjectsAsJsonBlob: true,
    file: $scope.conf.file
});
```

But the problem is the values that are passed along with the file are in format

Headers:

```
[{fieldName: "accessKeyId", value: "1111"},
{fieldName: "accessKey", value: "aaaa"}]
```

And I want it in form of:

```
{"accessKeyId": "1111", "accessKey": "aaaa"}
```

Please tell me the configuration I required to pass for this format.

Comment: you have to show more code, could you create a jsfiddle or plnkr or something?

Comment: I don't see Headers in your code for upload?

Comment: @Pindakaas: please refer angular-file-upload directive - https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: @HuyHoangPham:  please refer angular-file-upload directive - github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

please use

```
var data = angular.fromJson($scope.yourvariable);
```

and pass this variable in ajax call

Comment: Can you please specify where exactly in my function i have to place this function?

Comment: can you please tell me variable name of following value

[{fieldName: "accessKeyId", value: "1111"}
{fieldName: "accessKey", value: "aaaa"}]

Comment: It is passed inside result: [..]. You can refer http://jsfiddle.net/3t50b3fw/ this link for an example.

Comment: i can not understand what you want but in general if you want to pass object after convert into json .you can pass object in angular.fromJson.............object will convert into json format.let me know how you go